# Is there a way to stretch the whole display image to fit a given resolution?

Tags: python, pygame, resolution

I've been using pygame to make a game recently, and have ran into a little problem...

Basically, I would like to be able to stretch the whole image that is on the screen (all the things that I have blitted to it) into the resolution which the user has resized the window to. I've searched a lot on the documentation for pygame and on stack overflow and I can't seem to find an answer... Is it even possible? The source code for my game is pretty big atm, if anyone needs it I'll be willing to post it. Sorry if I made my question a little unclear :)

Comment: You're using windowed mode, always rendering at ex: 480x320 pixels, but you auto-upscale by a decimal to fill in the screen at ex: 1920x1280?

Comment: @monkey It's windowed mode 784x640 and It only really works at that resolution at the moment. I would like to be able to extend the window size AND the number of pixels per pixel at the same time, to keep the same amount of pixels high/wide the same, just at a different window resolution. If that makes any sense at all?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Blit everything to a separate surface (not directly to the screen), let's call it main_surface. Then blit the main_surface to the screen. 
Call `pygame.transform.scale(main_surface, (width, height)` with the new width and height that you get from the `VIDEORESIZE` event to scale the main_surface and everything in it to the new window dimensions.

Comment: Oh, thanks! I'll try doing that then. Seems like it should work ^_^

Comment: It works! Thanks! it is really laggy now though... is there a way to optimize this?

Comment: Make sure you call `.convert()` on all of your images before blitting them. Also make sure that you aren't creating a new surface every iteration. If this helped you, make sure you mark it as the selected answer with the checkmark.

Comment: Oh, it's fine now :D it wasn't any of the issues you mentioned, it was just a bit of unnecessary code that that I added in after having done what you told me to. Well, it definitely works fast now, but it can't seem to get any bigger without replacing the pixels past the standard resolution with black... Is it transforming my main_surface (as you called it) then cropping it to the standard resolution or something? Do I need to reset the size of the surface as well as resizing it...?

Comment: Yes, I could. I'll post it in pastebin for you... it's really inefficient and uncommented btw. it's my first attempt at making a game with pygame. Here: http://pastebin.com/ZpS0xNtb (and the whole game's in one module at the moment...is that bad?)

Comment: oh, I've also made an edit to it that allows it to be in fullscreen when you press f11. It's got some other stuff too... http://pastebin.com/62anv0SB