# Pygame, change resolution of my whole game

Tags: python, pygame, resolution

I have designed my whole pygame to work for 1920x1080 resolution.

However, I have to adapt it for smaller resoltion.

There is a lot of hardcoded value in the code.

Is there a simple way to change the resolution, like resizing the final image at the end of each loop, just before drawing it ?

Comment: You can resize the final image but that kind of kills the performance-saving point of having a smaller resolution. You should improve your code to work for any resolution.

Comment: could you explain a bit more of I can resize the final image ? my game isn't too hungry in performance so it should't be a problem

Comment: same question here? http://stackoverflow.com/a/18950357/902399

Answer (score 1):

You can use this : [pygame.transform.scale](http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/transform.html#pygame.transform.scale) or better (but less efficient) [pygame.transform.smoothscale](http://pygame.transform.smoothscale).

To do that, just change the reference surface where you draw (screen) to a generic surface. And after, just resize it, and put it on screen.

I can show you some code if you don't understand how it's work. Just ask.

Comment: You should not scale every frame.

Comment: The question was : Is there a simple way to change the resolution, like resizing the final image at the end of each loop, just before drawing it ?
This is the correct answer I hope. Ok, it's a performance killer, but, it's do the job. 
If all his works references his native resolution, it's the minimal code to handle all without modify all the code

Comment: Yes sure that was his question, but always a good idea to enligthen him that it's a bad solution(performance killer) and that there is better ways.

Comment: I'm, again, not agree with you. When you code, you should make choice : fast to code, fast to execute, fast to test, ... Each choice is personal. The problem was : "There is a lot of hardcoded value in the code.". This is very bad. Correct a such problem is not trivial or easy, and correct this problem solve his first question. So, the question (what is understand) is not "how to correct my bad coding", but "how can I do job with a minimal effort". I prefer to answer the original question, and my answer in this case is valid. Warning about perf was done previously in comment so, why worry?

Answer (score 1):

i usually create a `base resolution` and then whenever the screen is resized, i scale all the assets and surfaces by ratios.

This works well if you have assets that are of large resolution and you have scaled then down but would pixelate for smaller images.

you can also create multiple assets file for each resolution and when ever your resolution goes above one of the available asset resolution you can change the image. you can think in in context of `css media query` to better understand.

Comment: This should be the answer, when the screen size changes you should only scale all the assets ONCE and not scale the whole screen every frame.

Comment: yeah , and that could be achieved by calling the resize as an event callback for `VIDEORESIZE` event type.